# Howto send a valid XML POST request to ebay API via Python?

Tags: python, xml, http-post, ebay-api

I guess this is rather a general problem than ebay specific, but I am not sure: I am trying to send an XML request to the ebay developer API to retrieve an XML response. When using curl, everything works fine and I get an XML response telling me which API-keys are missing (if I would provide them via HTTP headers I would get a valid XML result):

```
curl -d '<!xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><findItemsByKeywordsRequest xmlns="http://www.ebay.com/marketplace/search/v1/services"><keywords>harry potter phoenix</keywords></findItemsByKeywordsRequest>' \
http://svcs.sandbox.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1
```

Which leads to the correct response:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<ms:errorMessage xmlns:ms="http://www.ebay.com/marketplace/services" xmlns="http://www.ebay.com/marketplace/search/v1/services">
    <error>
        <errorId>2038</errorId>
        <domain>CoreRuntime</domain>
        <severity>Error</severity>
        <category>System</category>
        <message>Missing SOA operation name header</message>
        <subdomain>System</subdomain>
    </error>
</ms:errorMessage>
```

But when I try to work with Python I just get "500 Internal Server error", no matter how basic I make my examples. I have tried two very basic methods:

Number one:

```
serverUrl = 'svcs.sandbox.ebay.com'
xmlparameters = '<!xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><findItemsByKeywordsRequest xmlns="http://www.ebay.com/marketplace/search/v1/services"><keywords>harry potter phoenix</keywords></findItemsByKeywordsRequest>'

webservice = httplib.HTTP(serverUrl)
webservice.putrequest("POST", "/services/search/FindingService/v1")
webservice.putheader("Host", serverUrl)
webservice.putheader("Content-type", "text/xml; charset=\"UTF-8\"")
webservice.putheader("Content-length", "%d" % len(xmlparameters))
webservice.endheaders()
webservice.send(xmlparameters)
```

Number two (which is my prefered method):

```
serverUrl = 'svcs.sandbox.ebay.com'
xmlparameters = '<!xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><findItemsByKeywordsRequest xmlns="http://www.ebay.com/marketplace/search/v1/services"><keywords>harry potter phoenix</keywords></findItemsByKeywordsRequest>'

connection = httplib.HTTPConnection(serverUrl)
connection.request("POST", '/services/search/FindingService/v1', xmlparameters)
```

As you can see in the CURL example, it does not matter that I do not send the API keys etc., it should return an XML error response anyway and not only HTTP status code "500 Internal server error".

Does anyone see what I am doing wrong with my POST request?

[EDIT]
btw using the URL ValueName API works perfectly with Python, but that’s just a GET request on a URL. Yet, I’d prefer to use the XML API. However, if that’s not possible I’d switch to ValueName URIs of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's returning a 500 status and the xml response:

```
>>> connection.request("POST", '/services/search/FindingService/v1', xmlparameters)
>>> resp = connection.getresponse()
>>> resp.status
<<< 500
>>> resp.read()
<<< '<?xml version=\'1.0\' encoding=\'UTF-8\'?><ms:errorMessage xmlns:ms="http://www.ebay.com/marketplace/services" xmlns="http://www.ebay.com/marketplace/search/v1/services"><error><errorId>2038</errorId><domain>CoreRuntime</domain><severity>Error</severity><category>System</category><message>Missing SOA operation name header</message><subdomain>System</subdomain></error></ms:errorMessage>'
```

Comment: You’re right… In Germany we use to say "not see the forest due to all the trees" in such situations. Always true ;) How embarassing. Thanks a lot! Would give you an upvote, but I have to think about a good OpenID username first ;)

Comment: Some addition if somebody finds this question in some months: ebay does not want an XML string at the beginning, otherwise it will return an error "Unable to create xml stream reader for XML: payload format incorrect or payload is empty". Removing the XML tag at the beginning makes everything work.

Answer (score 0):

The 500 response status is rather generic and should come back no matter what error is being thrown on the server.  Would you consider using the CGI trackback to return the error message?

http://docs.python.org/library/cgitb.html#module-cgitb

Comment: My script itself has no error, thus cgitb seems to return no error. I have enabled it in the first line and it returns a traceback when I produce an error in my code (e.g. call a variable which is not existant), but with my current code the whole script just runs fine: ">>> ebaypredict.sendRequest()
Error sending request: 500 Internal Server Error" (which is produced by a function checking if status code is good or not).

Comment: I guess you thought I was working with my wn webserver and thus recommended a CGI traceback tool? I am calling another webserver and that one is producing the error message, so I seem to send a wrong request to ebay somehow.